# angular + FosrestBundle + doctrine best way to update single property

Tags: angularjs, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

i am trying to use fosRestBundle to update an entity but i don't know how to do it properly.

i use doctrine and FOSRestBunble for the back and angular for the front (SPA application)

i want to update a property of an entity.
In my EntityRestController, i only have GET methods

Angular side, i don't have the full object but just an id, so i was trying to send data in the payload (whit the id of my entity and the data i want to update) but **i don't know how to get the payload data in the Patch method i created in EntityRestController**.

Is this the good way to do it ? i mean :
1. pass data in payload
2. get the entity by its id
3. update the entity

Or do i have to create a controller ? Because i will have to add a create action after and i think i will have to implements custom verifications

Thanks for your help

**EDIT : Here is what i try to do**

```
> php app/console route:debug
api_get_buildings                  GET        ANY      ANY    /api/buildings.{_format}
api_get_building                   GET        ANY      ANY    /api/buildings/{id}.{_format}
api_patch_building                 PATCH      ANY      ANY    /api/buildings/{request}.{_format}
```

my patch method :

```
public function patchBuildingAction($request)
{
    return $request->getContent();
}
```

When i call "http://myWebSide.dev/api/buildings" with PATCH method i have a symfony error

```
No route found for "PATCH /api/buildings": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, HEAD)
```

The same thing with GET method is ok

my fosrest config :

```
fos_rest:
param_fetcher_listener: true
body_listener: true
format_listener: true
view:
    view_response_listener: 'force'
    formats:
        xml: true
        json : true
    templating_formats:
        html: true
    force_redirects:
        html: true
    failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
    default_engine: twig
routing_loader:
    default_format: json
```

my routing.yml :

```
buildings:
type:         rest
resource:     "AppBundle:BuildingRest"
name_prefix:  api_
```

Comment: although it seems pretty old (and some stuff might not be compatible with the latest Symfony) it's a really big reference, so have a look here, basically your assumptions are right. http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/

Comment: or have a look here and extend the example by a patch route: http://jeremycurny.com/2016/03/27/symfony3-rest-api/

Comment: i read the links but it doesn't tell me how to get the payload data in the Patch method. Do you have a link with example xhere i can see the postman request for example and the patch method ?

Comment: $request->getContent()

Comment: as you can see in your update that only GET and HEAD are allowed - so you won't be able to PUT, POST, PATCH etc...

Comment: one reason for that can be CORS. e.g. check out https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle